# Fetching using react router loader doesn't work properly

Tags: reactjs, .net, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to retrieve an array of data from an API, but during the application it receives an empty response. When I access this call in a swagger, it returns the correct array.

HomePage.tsx:

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const books = useLoaderData();
  console.log(books);

  const bestOfMonthBooks = Array.isArray(books)
    ? books.filter((book) => !book.newRelease)
    : [];
  const newReleaseBooks = Array.isArray(books)
    ? books.filter((book) => book.newRelease)
    : [];

  return (
    <>
      <Carousel carouselData={DUUMY_CAROUSELITEMS} />

      <Await resolve={books}>
        <ListOfBooks books={bestOfMonthBooks} category="Best of month" />
        <ListOfBooks books={newReleaseBooks} category="New releases" />
      </Await>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

```js
async function loadBooks() {
  const response = await fetch("https://localhost:7276/GetAll");

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Something went wrong");
  } else {
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }
}

export function loader() {
  return defer({
    books: loadBooks,
  });
}
```

BookRepository.cs:

```cs
List<Book> books = new List<Book>()
        {
           new Book(1,"public/assets/Books/book 1.jpg","Hero With Gold"," Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Dougie Rogers",90,false),
           new Book(2,"pulbic/assets/Books/book 2.jpg","Goddes of Insanity","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Dennis Jenkins",90, false),
           new Book(3,"pulbic/assets/Books/book 3.jpg","Thieves Of The Lost World Of G","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Quinn Holland",90, false),
           new Book(4,"pulbic/assets/Books/book 4.jpg","Hunters Of Utopia","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Cole Porter",90, false),
           new Book(5,"pulbic/assets/Books/book 5.jpg","Lords And Gods","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Elis Booth",90, false),
           //new Book(6,"pulbic/assets/Books/book 6.jpg","Girls And Officers","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Victor Miller",90, false),
           new Book(7,"pulbic/assets/Books/book 7.jpg","Hero With Gold","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Dougie Rogers",90, true),
           new Book(8,"pulbic/assets/Books/book 8.jpg","Goddess Of Insanity","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Dennis Jenkins",90, true),
           new Book(9,"pulbic/assets/Books/book 9.jpg","Thieves Of The Lost World Of G","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Quinn Holland",90, true),
           new Book(10,"pulbic/assets/Books/book 10.jpg","Hunters Of Utopia","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Cole Porter",90, true),
           new Book(11,"pulbic/assets/Books/book 11.jpg","Lords And Gods","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Elis Booth",90, true),
           //new Book(12,"pulbic/assets/Books/book 12.jpg","Girls And Officers","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua","Victor Miller",90, true),
        };
        public BookRepository()
        {

        }
        public List<Book> GetAll()
        {
            return books;
        }
```

object returned from loader:

```
books: async ƒ loadBooks()
length: 0
name: "loadBooks"
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
[[FunctionLocation]]: HomePage.tsx:56
```

I tried to return to the loader in the bookmodel array and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue(s)

The `loader` function doesn't return any data, it is just returning the `loadBooks` function.

> ```
> export function loader() {
>   return defer({
>     books: loadBooks, // <-- function value returned!
>   });
> }
> ```

The `HomePage` component is also missing about half the code it needs to correctly render deferred data loading.

See the [Deferred Data](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred) guide for more details.

## Solution

1. Update your `loader` function to return the ***result*** of having called `loadBooks`. In other words, actually invoke the `loadBooks` function.

   ```js
   export function loader() {
     return defer({
       books: loadBooks()
     });
   }
   ```
2. Update `Homepage` render a `Suspense` component around `Await` and provide `Carousel` as the fallback UI while the data is fetched, and use a children render function to access the resolved deferred `books` data.

   ```
   import { Suspense } from "react";
   import { Await, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";

   const HomePage = () => {
     const data = useLoaderData();

     console.log({ data }); // <-- Promise object!

     return (
       <Suspense fallback={<Carousel carouselData={DUUMY_CAROUSELITEMS} />}>
         <Await resolve={data.books}>
           {(books) => {
             console.log({ books }); // <-- books array response value

             const bestOfMonthBooks = Array.isArray(books)
               ? books.filter((book) => !book.newRelease)
               : [];
             const newReleaseBooks = Array.isArray(books)
               ? books.filter((book) => book.newRelease)
               : [];

             return (
               <>
                 <ListOfBooks
                   books={bestOfMonthBooks}
                   category="Best of month"
                 />
                 <ListOfBooks books={newReleaseBooks} category="New releases" />
               </>
             );
           }}
         </Await>
       </Suspense>
     );
   };
   ```

### Demo

[image: Edit fetching-using-react-router-loader-doesnt-work-properly]